# Android XML Layout Design

Tags: android, xml

I have the xml design code of android. I want the design a bit different. Following is the relative layout what I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="sg.unitconverter.UnitFuel"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_unit_fuel">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:entries="@array/area"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:entries="@array/area"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clear"
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/backspace"
        android:id="@+id/backSpace"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/clear"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/num7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/num8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/num7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/backSpace"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/backSpace"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/num9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/num8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/num8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/num8"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/num4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/num5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/num4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num8"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/num8"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/num6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/num5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/num5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/num5"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/num5"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/num3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/num2"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/num0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/num2"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:id="@+id/dot"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/num0"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/equal"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/num0"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/num3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The output of above xml shows like the following:
[image]

But I want the design to be like the following:
[image]

Can anyone please help on this to do atleast something so that it would be great?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go.. this is just basic layout.. you need to color and custom it by your self

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="From"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="To"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to look at Google's Material design documentation.

https://material.io/guidelines/

For the Buttons:
https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html